# python string operation. sticked words separation

Tags: python, string

I have a pretty challenging problem here I need your help.

the problem is this:

I have a string for example "abcde"

Now, I want to separate this string into any possible ordered combinations as a list of strings.
for example,

```
my_function('abcde')

output = 
[
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'de'],
 ['a', 'b', 'cde'],
 ['a', 'bced'],
 ['a', 'b', 'cd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'bc', 'de'],
 ['a', 'bcd', 'e'],
 ['a', 'bcde'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['ab', 'c', 'de'],
 ['ab', 'cd', 'e'],
 ['ab', 'cde'],
 ['abc','d','e'],
 ['abc', 'de'],
 ['abcd', 'e'],
 ['abcde']
]
```

It is not quite the permutation since the order matters.

Comment: In your example, the output is 17 lists. Does the order of these lists matter? I get that the order of the strings in each list matters, but does the order of the lists themselves matter?

Comment: Order of the lists does not matter. I might have missed out some list in the output list. But basically I would like to get all the lists of strings that are formed using the input string's alphabet ['a','b','c','d','e'].

Comment: ` I might have missed out some list in the output list` <- this confuses my understanding of the problem. Could you please edit your question to include the full list of outputs (perhaps for a smaller string, if that makes the example more tractable)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same result without itertools:

```py
s = 'python'
splits = len(s) - 1
output = []
for i in range(2 ** splits):
    combination = []
    word = ''
    for position in range(splits + 1):
        word += s[position]
        if not (i & (1 << position)):
            combination.append(word)
            word = ''
    output.append(combination)
output.sort()

for combination in output:
    print(combination)
```

Just for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
import itertools

def get_slices(values):
    slices_len = len(values) - 1

    for is_slice in itertools.product([True, False], repeat=slices_len):
        start_index = 0
        slices = []

        for slice_index, is_index_slice in enumerate(is_slice, 1):
            if is_index_slice:
                index_slice = values[start_index:slice_index]
                start_index = slice_index

                slices.append(index_slice)

        slices.append(values[start_index:])

        yield slices
```

Most important part of this code is the `itertools.product` call at the beginning, this generates all possible types of slices. A slice definition here corresponds to a bunch of `bool`s representing whether two adjacent elements at all indices of pairs in `values` (there are `slices_len` of these) are joined or not.

`list(get_slices("abcde))` will return the `list` you requested. If you don't need all results immediately, and instead want to iterate through them, you don't need the surrounding `list` call.

If you want the reverse order, you can switch the `[True, False]` with `[False, True]`.

Answer (score 1):

i got 16 items and you have 17 :-)

```
    def fn(base_str):
        result = [[base_str]]
        for i in range(1, len(base_str)):
            child = fn(base_str[i:])
            for x in child:
                x.insert(0, base_str[0:i])
            result = child + result
        return result


    print(fn("abcde"))
```

Comment: Oh, just realized that I repeated [a, bcde] twice